# CLION IDE C++, C, and Make not found

Tags: c++, c, clion

I am using Clion 1.2 and Windows 10 64 bit and have installed mingw from http://nuwen.net/mingw.html#install but when setting up tool-chains the environment and cmake is found but not c and the c++ compiler although I have pointed to the distribution. I know that the compilers are installed since I opened up the terminal to verify it. Does anyone have any suggestions on why the compilers in CLion aren't found?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @DonquiseParker Not yet supported... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-885